# User and password included internally in the code

Tags: c#, database, winforms, security

I wrote WinForm application using C#. The application needs to be connected to a database, so it contains code such:

```
String connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
                    "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                    "localhost", "3456", "username",
                    "password", "databasename" );
```

That means that the user and the password of the database server is included internally in the application. I think this is not a secure way. Is there any way can give more security?

Comment: possible duplicate of [encrypt SQL connectionstring c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160515/encrypt-sql-connectionstring-c-sharp)

Comment: @TLiebe Not really a duplicate as the OP was not aware that you could encrypt a connection string in the first place, he was looking for options on how to make his application more secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an encrypted connection string to your app.config.

For more information : [Securing Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This is definitely the way to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a local file and then use system permissions to make it hard to modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ignore this problem.
2. Let the user enter database username/password
3. Don't connect to a database, but connect to a Http service, so you don't leak the database connection password any way.