# Encrypt database user & password

Tags: c#, nlog

Nlog has the ability to write logs to database.
For this to happen you need to supply user/pass in nlog config or web config.

Is there a way to encrypt it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160515/encrypt-sql-connectionstring-c-sharp

Comment: Nope. Sadly I cant encrypt custom configuration section in web.config in this way

Comment: Have you considered using a [web service as a target](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/WebService_target)?

Comment: @rails - Please explain in detail the reason you use that suggestion?  You asked how you would do it, and thats exactly how, you would do it.  The same tool that can encrypt Web.config can encrypt the configuration file on a desktop based application.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx).

Add the following class to your project:

```
class Encryption
{
    static byte[] entropy = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Add some entropy");

    public static string EncryptString(System.Security.SecureString input)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(
            System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ToInsecureString(input)),
            entropy,
            System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }

    public static SecureString DecryptString(string encryptedData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(
                Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData),
                entropy,
                System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            return ToSecureString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new SecureString();
        }
    }

    public static SecureString ToSecureString(string input)
    {
        SecureString secure = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            secure.AppendChar(c);
        }
        secure.MakeReadOnly();
        return secure;
    }

    public static string ToInsecureString(SecureString input)
    {
        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(input);
        try
        {
            returnValue = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Use the following syntax to get the encrypted password string:

```
var encryptedPassword = Encryption.EncryptString(
    Encryption.ToSecureString("yourPassword"));
```

In the configuration file, make sure to replace the clear password with the content of the `encryptedPassword` for the database target:

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
  name="d1"
  dbUserName="log"
  dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
  dbDatabase="NLog"
  dbPassword="AQAAA... + the rest of the encryptedPassword string"
  dbHost="TheLogServer"
  commandText="INSERT INTO [LOG] VALUES (@p)">
  <parameter layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" name="p" />
</target>
```

Create a method which will replace the `DBPassword` of your current class logger and will return the logger with the decrypted password:

```
static Logger logger = GetLogger();

private static Logger GetLogger()
{
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    var d1 = (DatabaseTarget)logger.Factory.Configuration
        .AllTargets.Where(t => t.Name == "d1").FirstOrDefault();
    d1.DBPassword = Encryption.ToInsecureString(
        Encryption.DecryptString(((NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout)(d1.DBPassword)).Text));
    return logger;
}
```

Use the logger as you have used it just until now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LogEventInfo myEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "My debug message");
    myEvent.LoggerName = logger.Name;
    myEvent.Properties.Add("MyCustomValue", "This is from MyClass");
    logger.Log(myEvent);
}
```